# Coding-style conventions in Isabelle/Isar

Tags: isabelle, jedit, isar

**TL;DR**: Are there any coding conventions for the Isar language? Is it necessary to respect jEdit's folding strategy?

---

My team is working on the formalization of mathematics, so one of our main purposes is to obtain readable proofs. Looking into that, we tried to code proofs in a way that intermediate facts (and labels, if any) stand out:

```
from fact1 have
  1: "Foo"
  using Thm1 Thm2 by auto
then have
  2: "Bar = FooBar"
  by simp
also from 1 have
  " ... = BarFoo"
  by blast
```

etc. Apart from the fact that sometimes this produces a proliferation of "short lines" (btw, I don't know if this is really a problem), it is somehow not compatible with jEdit folding strategy; after folding, the previous code block would look like this:

```
from fact1 have
then have
also from 1 have
```

completely obscuring the argument. The following format perhaps is better:

```
from fact1
have 1: "Foo"
  using Thm1 Thm2 by auto
then 
have 2: "Bar = FooBar"
  by simp
also from 1 
have " ... = BarFoo"
  by blast
```

And, after folding,

```
from fact1
have 1: "Foo"
then 
have 2: "Bar = FooBar"
also from 1 
have " ... = BarFoo"
```

which makes the flow of the argument explicit.

In any case, before I come up with 5 new formatting conventions, I'd definitely like to know if there is some de facto standard, or at least if someone thought about this.

Comment: Well, there is this: https://proofcraft.org/blog/isabelle-style.html

Comment: Other than that I don't really know. I usually make a line break to separate the statement from the method used to prove it; apart from that, I only make line breaks when the lines get too long. I also don't think I've seen many people actually use jEdit's folding. I certainly don't, although it might actually be useful. It's just not in my workflow somehow.

Comment: I’m not aware of a syntax style guide either. We’re thinking of writing one, along the lines of what you have under ‘the following format perhaps is better’, but it will take a while to come out. It’s usually a good idea to not fight jedit, and to go with what works well with folding, default indentation etc, which still leaves a lot of freedom.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. Both count as upvotable answers to me.

Comment: @lsf37 another idea going around, implicit in the examples above, is first to quote local facts (from, with) and later theorems and lemmas (using). I believe this also contributes to readability.